# Matrices whose entries are polynomials

Tags: performance, matrix, sympy

When using the `sympy` library, what is the most efficient way of operating with matrices whose entries are polynomials?

I tried both storing symbols and storing `Poly` instances as entries of a `Matrix` object. In each case, the performance that I get for operations like matrix multiplication seems to be an order of magnitude slower than what I get with `sage`.

Comment: Try using `ring()` instead of `Poly`.

Comment: In this case, I am getting ``SympifyError``s when constructing matrices that I'm not quite sure how to handle. E.g., I successfully managed to construct row matrices that contain polynomial entries, but when I call ``Matrix`` to merge the rows I get said error.